# How to target the current hovering class when there are other same classes using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to target the current hovering class when there are other classes with the same name? I see a lot of similar questions but all of the problems are solved with Jquery. Is it possible to use JavaScript with this question?

I want to add a star icon on every product picture. It will only appear when the picture is hovered. When the star is clicked, the star will toggle from `.starsolid` to `.starsolid-close`. However, the hover effect only appears on the first child, which also disables the toggle effect.

here's my code

Btw this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, so if there is something that I could've done better making this a better question, please tell me. Thanks!

```html
    <div class = "product divbox">
                <ul class = "horizontalpic">
                    <li class='productpic img1' onmouseover='setsolidstar()' onmouseout='setoriginalstar()'>
                        <a href="" ></a>
                        <div class = fakebutton></div>
                        <div class = 'star' ><i class="far fa-star fa-s"  style = color:black ></i></div>
                        <div class = 'star starsolid'><i class="fas fa-star fa-s" style = color:black></i></div>
                        <h3 class = 'productname'>coco crush</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'productdiscription'>菱格紋圖騰，窄版，18K BEIGE米色金</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'price'>NT$ 44,000*</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'discover'><a href="">查看詳情  ></a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li class='productpic img2' onmouseover='setsolidstar()' onmouseout='setoriginalstar()'>
                        <a href="" ></a>
                        <div class = fakebutton></div>
                        <div class = 'star' ><i class="far fa-star fa-s"  style = color:black ></i></div>
                        <div class = 'star starsolid'><i class="fas fa-star fa-s" style = color:black></i></div>
                        <h3 class = 'productname'>coco crush</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'productdiscription'>菱格紋圖騰，窄版，18K BEIGE米色金</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'price'>NT$ 44,000*</h3>
                        <h3 class = 'discover'><a href="">查看詳情  ></a></h3>
                    </li></ul></div>
```

I used `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` to create the hover effect. For the toggle effect, when clicked on the `.fakebutton` div the `.starsolid` and `.starsolid-close` will toggle.

```js
    const starhover = () => {
    const star = document.querySelector('.productpic .star');
    const starsolid = document.querySelector('.productpic .starsolid');
    const fakebutton = document.querySelector('.productpic .fakebutton');

    fakebutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        starsolid.classList.toggle('starsolid-close');
        starsolid.style.transition = 'ease 0.5s';
     }); starhover();
    function setsolidstar(){
       document.querySelector('.productpic .star').style.opacity = '1';
       document.querySelector('.productpic .star').style.transition = 'ease 0.5s';
    }                                                                    
     function setoriginalstar(){
    document.querySelector('.productpic .star').style.opacity = '0';}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understand you correctly. Here I make the star (the "S") visible when hovering the product. When clicking the star the class name "solid" will be toggled. So, the solid star will stay when you move the cursor away from the product.

I add the click event listener to the `<ul>` element. This is much more flexible because items could be added the list on a later stage. So, the only thing I need to check for is if the target of the click event has "star" in the class name. If so I toogle "solid". And then the rest is up to the CSS.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('ul.horizontalpic').addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('star')){
      e.target.classList.toggle('solid');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.horizontalpic {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.productpic {
  border: solid black thin;
  margin: .5em;
}

.star {
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover .star {
  visibility: visible;
}

.star.solid {
  visibility: visible;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="product divbox">
  <ul class="horizontalpic">
    <li class='productpic img1'>
      <a href=""></a>
      <div class=f akebutton></div>
      <div class='star'>S</div>
      <h3 class='productname'>coco crush</h3>
      <h3 class='productdiscription'>菱格紋圖騰，窄版，18K BEIGE米色金</h3>
      <h3 class='price'>NT$ 44,000*</h3>
      <h3 class='discover'><a href="">查看詳情  ></a></h3>
    </li>
    <li class='productpic img2'>
      <a href=""></a>
      <div class=f akebutton></div>
      <div class='star'>S</div>
      <h3 class='productname'>coco crush</h3>
      <h3 class='productdiscription'>菱格紋圖騰，窄版，18K BEIGE米色金</h3>
      <h3 class='price'>NT$ 44,000*</h3>
      <h3 class='discover'><a href="">查看詳情  ></a></h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Now I'm able to make the star appear when hovering on each picture. I just have to change up the code a bit to make the toggle work. Thank you

Comment: Just want to get everything clear. Can you explain in detail how the JS code determine whether I'm clicking the first S or the second S? Thank You lots!

Comment: @Ming The **e** refers to the event. In this case it is a click event and the click event holds information about the click, one of which is the target -- the element that was clicked. In my code the event listener is on the ul element so potentially the click event could have any of the elements as target, but I'm only changing the class if the the class name of the target is "star".

Comment: how does the clock event know which "star" class I clicked on?

Comment: When I do the test `if(e.target.classList.contains('star')){` I know that it (`e.target`) is an element with the class name "star". So I don't need to know more.